# Normalize or not - one to many or lots of columns

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, denormalization

I cannot decide whether to normalize or denormalize this part of my database:

I have a list of ~50 species that are either present or absent at a given sample point. These 50 will maybe expand to 75 in the future, but no more. The primary purpose of this database is generating reports. So if there are 10 sites in a given area, an average question will be: in how many of those sites did we detect species a?

Should I create 50 t/f bit columns:

site, a, b,c,d,e...n

1, t, f, t, f ,t ,t ....

2, f, t, t, f, t ,f.....

Or should I create a one-to-many table:

1 a

1 c
...

2 b

2 c ...

I know the tendency is towards normalization and 70 columns may be daunting to other users, but I really like the idea of drawing data from the denormalized version. Is one truly better in this case?

Comment: The version with the 50 - 75 columns is not denormalized.  You normalize the data, not the representation of the data (boolean).  The only advantage to putting each sample / species on a separate row is that you don't have to create the rows that are false.  If you only have an average of 5 species present in a sample, you only have 5 rows, rather than 50.  If you have an average of 45 species in a sample, there's no advantage.

Comment: I'd go with the 2nd alternative (many-to-many table), since it'll simplify the use of aggregate functions, e.g. if you want to count how many species were recorded at each site.

Answer (score 0):

Advantage of the 50 column solution:

- Access to all species on a given sample point will be efficient.

Advantages of the one-to-many solution:

- Increasing the number of species can be done without a redesign of the database, just by entering new records containing the species id.
- Access to all sample points containing a given species will be easier than on the 50 column design.

Being in the trade for several decades, I'm generally wary of requirements like "maybe expand to 75 in the future, but no more". But if the increase of species doesn't happen too frequently, and if you have time to stop your application and reorganize your table in that case, that argument isn't too strong. However, I'd also be wary of the restriction to query your data by species only. In many cases, the need for the opposite direction will arise eventually.